# How can I add soap web service as reference in .NET 5.0

Tags: c#, .net, web, soap, service

When I try Microsoft WCF Web Service Reference Provider I get this error:

> the connected services component 'Microsoft WCF Web Service Reference
> Provider' failed (HRESULT:0x80131500)  The target framework
> 'net5.0-windows' is not supported .NET Core, .NET Standart, or a .NET
> Framework version. The minimum supported framework versions are as
> follows: netcoreapp 1.0, netstandart 1.3 and net4.5

How can I add the web service links?

Comment: Can this help   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66642066/net-5-0-and-soap-web-services ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed net5.0-windows to net5.0 in the csproj file. Added the webservice reference, then changed the csproj file back to net5.0-windows. This solved it.